# react-data-table-component v-^7.5.2 how to first columns fixed col

Tags: reactjs, datatable, fixed, react-data-table-component

I try this add style but it's not working add component fixedColumn similar but not working

```
.rdt_TableHead .rdt_TableCol.fixed-left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.rdt_TableBody .rdt_TableCol.fixed-left {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[image: My datatable]